# Sum of changing termes serie

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am looking towards which value tends the sum of the inverses of the odd numbers going from 1 / (2k + 1) to 1 / (4k-1) when k tends towards + infinity :

- for k = 1 there is just 1/3
- for k = 2 it is the sum of 1/5 + 1/7 = 0.3428.....
- for k = 3 it is the sum of 1/7 + 1/9 + 1/11 = 0.3448....
- for k = 4 it is the sum of 1/9 + 1/11 + 1/13 + 1/15 = 0.3456....
- Etc...

If we go further, it seems to tend towards ln(2)/2=0.346573... when k tends towards infinity but with my scientific High School Diploma I have a little trouble seeing how to prove it ... Would there be a "simple enough" solution that would be accessible to me?

Thank you

Comment: this is a good question, but a bit off-topic here, let me answer in a comment: for large $k$ you can approximate the sum $\sum_{p=k}^{2k-1}\frac{1}{2p+1}$ by an integral over $p$, which equals $\frac{1}{2} \ln \left(\frac{4 k-1}{2 k+1}\right)$. Then taking the limit $k\rightarrow\infty$ you end up with $\tfrac{1}{2}\ln 2$, as you guessed.

Comment: Thank you very much Carlo ;)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as stated by @CarloBeenakker, it is a good question but out of topic here.  Carlo already answered in a nice way in his comment, but if you want to get a "canonical" answer I advise you to post your question to our sister site [Mathematics StackExchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), devoted explicitly to general (even very difficult) questions in Mathematics.

Comment: Ok, I wanted to add a following question on linked subject Riemann series theorem here but I will other there if you prefer. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Done : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345183/validity-of-the-riemann-series-theorem